# Login Failed while settting up transactional replication on a single computer

Tags: sql-server, transactional-replication

I'm trying to learn how to implement transactional replication on SQL Server by testing it out on my PC. Is it possible to set up transactional replication on a single PC, using 2 SQL Server instances, and 1 Windows account?

My attempts so far have led to various errors in the replication monitor. I have my Publisher and Distributor set up on an instance called `SQLDEVELOPER` and my subscriber set up on an instance called `QLDEVELOPER2`. The most recent error I got were these two:

```
The process could not connect to Subscriber 'xxxxxx\SQLDEVELOPER2'.
    (Source: MSSQL_REPL, Error number: MSSQL_REPL20084)

Get help: http://help/MSSQL_REPL20084

Login failed for user 'NT Service\SQLAgent$SQLDEVELOPER'. 
    (Source: MSSQLServer, Error number: 18456)

Get help: http://help/18456
```

It seems that the distributor can't connect to the subscriber. I think there's some permission issues going on. My snapshot agent security is set to run under the SQL Server Agent service account rather than my Windows account. I chose run under the SQL Server Agent service when setting up security for both the publisher and the subscriber.

Comment: Hi and welcome to our community!  MS Docs has a nice tutorial on how to [Configure replication between two fully connected servers (transactional)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/tutorial-replicating-data-between-continuously-connected-servers?view=sql-server-ver15). Follow it step by step and you'll get the desired result. (Hint: Instead of 4 different users  you can use only one)